# Representation of Pair(Apache Commons) object in JSON format

Tags: java, angularjs, json, rest

I have a REST API implemented as follows:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "url/url", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    MessageQueueResponse getOutboundQueueMessages (@RequestBody(required=true)Myclass myclass, @RequestParam(value = "value", required = true) String value)
    {
       //something
    }

class Myclass {
    Pair<Date,Date> range;
    //getter, setters etc
}
```

From client side I am trying to send this as JSON:

```
    var d = new Date();
    var n = d.toJSON();

    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'url/url',
        params: {value:"myvalue"},
        data: {range:{n:n}}
    }).success(function(response){
        //after success
    }).error(function(){
        //after failure
    });
```

I am getting 400 Bad request. How to represent Pair object in json format at client side?

Comment: Did you try `range: { left: xxxx, right: xxxxx }`? that would make more sense IMHO, but maybe you should introduce a range class of your own

Comment: I did try but it isn't working. APIs are provided by someone else, so do not want to change. Thanks.

Comment: It worked with left  `{ left: xxxx, right: xxxxx} `. But the date can be only provided in milliseconds format.